# Trying to find element in an array from which the sum of elements on the left side is equal to elements on the right. Could you optimise my approach?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def balancedSums(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(0, n):
        lsum = sum(arr[0 : i])
        rsum = sum(arr[i + 1 : n])
        if lsum == rsum:
            return "YES"
    return "NO"
```

I am getting all test cases but two, failing due to timeout. What are my options?

Comment: You could keep running totals as you iterate instead of adding up the whole left and right sides every turn. You could avoid making slices of your list.

Comment: Where is this from? Please give the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
def balancedSums(arr):
    lsum = 0
    rsum = sum(arr)
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(0, n):
        rsum -= arr[i]
        if lsum == rsum:
            return "YES"
        lsum += arr[i]
    return "NO"
```

The time-complexity of this is `O(n)`

Comment: yeah of course. Thx for the heads-up

Comment: @khelwood ig that was what he was going for. I got the idea anyway.

Comment: @DanielHao, may I ask you why is that?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, my code uses the same steps as his... the first iteration doesn't add anything to the left sum `lsum`

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode yes, you're right... thx a lot for the heads-up

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode done

Comment: When I run this with `balancedSums([1, 2, 3])` I get `'YES'`.  Shouldn't it be `'NO'`?

Comment: @Bill, try now... there was a line from earlier edit I forgot to change..

Comment: @Anwarvic. Okay it works now.  But in my test it's 3 times slower (and more lines) than the OP's code!

Comment: @Bill 3 times slower despite being linear instead of quadratic? On what input?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Must have misread 'ms' as 'µs'! It is about 290 times faster than the OPs code in my test.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to think of a vectorized way to do this with Numpy.  This is the best I have come up with so far:

```
import numpy as np

def balancedSums(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    ltr = np.cumsum(arr)
    rtl = np.cumsum(arr[::-1])[::-1]
    if np.any(ltr == rtl):
        return "YES"
    else:
        return "NO"

assert(balancedSums([1, 2, 3]) == "NO")
assert(balancedSums([3, 2, 1, 2, 3]) == "YES")
assert(balancedSums([10]) == "YES")
assert(balancedSums([1, 1]) == "NO")
assert(balancedSums([0]) == "YES")
assert(balancedSums([]) == "NO")
```

Comment: Forget this!  It's about 8 times slower than @Anwarvic's answer.

Comment: Okay, I had a `sum` in there.  Now it's about 20 times faster than @Anwarvic's answer.

Comment: 20 times faster on what data?

Comment: I used an array with 2001 elements: `x = np.random.randint(10, size=1000); arr = np.concatenate([x, [0], x[::-1]])`

Comment: Something like `rtl = ltr[-1] - ltr` could perhaps be slightly faster.

Comment: @don't talk just code.  Thanks. Nice idea. Not quite that easy though. This works: `rtl = np.full(ltr.shape, ltr[-1]); rtl[1:] -= ltr[:-1]`. But it wasn't any faster in my test.

Comment: In [my test](https://tio.run/##rZO7bsIwFIZ3P8UREsKBQBOgS6QMrdS1HTpVKIoMONRSfBI5TiuentpOIKHQAVQPuZzL7@/3pdzrzwIXh0OmCglaSC40CFkWSoPiJWeatH9Yy3IPrAIsCdnyDAoldgJZTplSXkTADIQYco4u4gJZoUCAQFAMd5wGPmBbakde1dJ0mKftWAUQgUi8U1qdpwVMIDQl2CsRWSsSu@pO2vVzXSuEwcfL@4D0A69vg8bCE34z9SU2PQstU0AuCbx7PDqJaQzOQXIn@Alscib0p5/5LYYsP7P8JnKF@z@Qr9M@i7x/eHKtDBqWs00tzwCVzn8nVlE0DROveZGWzlQw3FOnE9uu/ja4yanja1R5XvHLvIHzCMlq3FRmzuMR908r233NfWeAGBpTuZrDGMJgPF4mx49O5vbmR3JMCdS00ooyzzvbqYTYv7Q7d4vWrQ3biW3GAXQmtRGUAmlzsWnO5HrLIlflVtu3l3zNVRwGZrYHQ3JqLZUFGQ2XszADWY1gCFRbWL4wbVZhlqbIJE/TZnmbBu9w@AE) you're between Anwarvic and

Comment: its obvious "optimization" (13 ms vs their 16 and 10 ms).

Comment: Ah, it's because I was testing with a np.array whereas you are testing with a list. If OP's arr is a list then my numpy solution is no faster. If `arr` is already a np.array then mine is 50 times faster than Anwarvic2 in your test.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a list of ints. The only other question the OP asked was about HackerRank, and [this HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-array/problem) looks like what this question is about.

Comment: I made a slight mod to my code which should improve it in the case where `arr` is a list.  Try your speed test again!

Comment: Yes, that dropped it to ~6.5 ms.